# with JavaScript i want to have the following output

Tags: javascript, arrays

Output an array where a value is added to the next value of the array. The Last value will be added with the first value.

Example:
[45, 4, 9, 16, 25]
Converted to:
[49, 13, 25, 41, 70]

Map() method must be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Array.prototype.map()` you can use the index parameter and in each iteration 
 to see if it's the end of the array or not like so:

```js
const arr = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

const newArr = arr.map((item, i) => {
  return i !== (arr.length - 1) ? item + arr[i + 1] : item + arr[0];
})

console.log(newArr);
```

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```js
console.log([45, 4, 9, 16, 25].map((item, index, array) => item + array[(index + 1) % array.length]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
const nums = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

const newNums = nums.map((item, index) => {
  if(index < nums.length - 1) {
    return item + nums[ index + 1]
  }
    return item + nums[0]
})

console.log(newNums) // [ 49, 13, 25, 41, 70 ]
```